# How to apply Gaussian blur on a polygon drawn inside a larger image

Tags: python, gaussian, scikit-image

I want to apply Gaussian blur on pixel coordinates of a polygon inside a larger image and then do something with the blurred polygon on the same coordinates. The [draw polygon](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.draw.html#skimage.draw.polygon) function that exists in `skimage` gives me the coordinates directly of the image and not a mask. I ideally want to apply the filter on the mask itself but the `draw polygon` function doesn't get me the mask.

```
img = np.zeros((10, 10), dtype=np.uint8)
r = np.array([1, 2, 8, 1])
c = np.array([1, 7, 4, 1])
rr, cc = polygon(r, c)
# Apply Gaussian blur here on the locations specified by the polygon
img[rr, cc] = 1 # or do something else on the blurred positions.
```

I can't obviously run the Gaussian blur on the image first because if I ran the Gaussian blur on `rr, cc`, I would get decimal values and won't be able to access the same polygon by indexing. How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved it.

```
mask = np.zeros_like(img)
mask[rr, cc] = 1  # or anything else on the blurred positions
mask = filters.gaussian(mask, sigma=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

SciPy's [Gaussian blur](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter.html) doesn't take a mask as an input, so you'll need to blur the whole image and then copy the values over for just that polygon. In that case, you're ok with the indices:

```py
from skimage import filters

img_blurred = filters.gaussian(img)
img_poly_blurred = np.copy(img)  # don't modify img in-place unless you're sure!
img_poly_blurred[rr, cc] = img_blurred[rr, cc]
```